# Assessments of depression: Does the rate of false positives vary between the qualification of those testing?

Tags: methodology, clinical-psychology, psychiatry, depression

A friend recently asked me an interesting question to which I couldn't find the answer. Does the accuracy of depression assessments vary by the profession i.e. Nurse, GP Vs Clinical Psychologist, Psychiatrist etc, of those conducting the assessment? What is the difference in false positives or misdiagnosis between these professions.

I am aware the forms used are mostly the same but does the diagnosis accuracy vary?

Comment: Certainly this may depend on the instrument and method of measurement. Consider a self-report instrument (eg the [CES-D](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/014662167700100306)). The researcher effect here would be non-existent, as the scoring involves simply adding up the number of responses. That said, training (a large factor in [inter-rater reliability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability)) for diagnosis widely varies among those professions and would play a large role in diagnosis using an observation-based assessment. Are you thinking of a specific instrument?